# Write this as sum: $a_{0}+4a_{1}+7a_{2}+10a_{3}+13a_{4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, arithmetic

> Write this as sum: $a_{0}+4a_{1}+7a_{2}+10a_{3}+13a_{4}$
>
> (Hint: This is an arithmetic sequence)

From hint (arithmetic), I know that the trick of this sequence is that the difference of 2 neighbor numbers is always $3$.

But really no idea how to write this as sum?

$$\sum_{i=0}^{4}something \cdot a_{i}$$

I don't know how to make this difference $3$ in this sum very complicated? : /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are searching for

$$\sum_{i=0}^4 (3i+1)a_i.$$

**Edit**

How to find this ?

You were on the right track when you said that the difference between to consecutive terms is $3$ (without the $a_i$). You then know that the factor of the arithmetic-geometric progression is $3$. Then you just have to find the "$+1$".

Comment: I check now with tests but how can you know this so fast? I was thinking about 30 minutes then I gave up and ask here.. Very annoying this is.

Comment: @cnmesr I will edit to add that kind of information.

Comment: Thank you very much for detail I will try it on other example later! Thanks a lot :)